# ng-repeat is not working with ng-app value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-app

The directive `ng-repeat` is not working properly when we give `ng-app="MyApp"` and which is working without passing any value to the `ng-app` directive which is a strange behaviour to me. I am new to the AngularJS. Is this behaviour expected?

Please throw some light on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Books Buddy</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-init="books=['EffectiveJava','ServletBlackbook','CodeCleaner','HeadFirstJava']">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="book in books">{{book}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add your angular.module code.

Comment: yes, this is how angular work.... because you are initiating your array inside html so you don't need to declare any app name...... in other case if you are initiating your array through controller so you need to make a custom app and work inside a controller...

Comment: Thank you for reply @AkshayKumar, So it means that even if i try with some small operations like ng-model also, ng-app should not contains ng-app="myApp" right?

Comment: yes, you can try ng-model also without declaring any app name... but i recommend the practice of making your own custom app.. because its a best practice..

Comment: You cannot use a named app in ng-app if you do not provide the stuff via `angular.module('MyApp', []);`

Answer (score 1):

When using only ngInit and no controllers, directives or services, you don't need the ngApp. That's how angular works. If you're specifying MyApp as your ngApp angular won't be able to find it and then you get your error.

Answer (score 0):

Just male `ng-app=''` it should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Books Buddy</title></head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">
 <div ng-init="books=['EffectiveJava','ServletBlackbook','CodeCleaner','HeadFirstJava']">
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="book in books">{{book}}
   </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your way (here we are doing every thing in html only so we don't need custom app.. we can just say "hey angular just do what you can do with things")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Books Buddy</title></head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
 <div ng-init="books=['EffectiveJava','ServletBlackbook','CodeCleaner','HeadFirstJava']">
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="book in books">{{book}}
   </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a correct way (in this we are declaring our own app so we need to set a name for our app..)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Books Buddy</title></head>
<body ng-app = "myApp">
 <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="book in books">{{book}}</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.books = ['EffectiveJava','ServletBlackbook','CodeCleaner','HeadFirstJava'];
    });

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model` on books, and here there is no need to wright `ng-app="myApp"`because You are not initializing you app seperately, above code is not that dynamic so you can use ng-app directly

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Books Buddy</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app >
<div ng-init="books=['EffectiveJava','ServletBlackbook','CodeCleaner','HeadFirstJava']">
 <div ng-model="books" >
  <ul ng-repeat="book in books" >
    <li>{{book}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```